# Lookup component having search and create ability in flow

Tags: visual-workflow, lookup, screen-flow, lookup-field, flow-screen-component

Is there any way we can utilize the lookup component available inside the record page, where we have the ability to either search for a record or create a new record altogether, be available in a flow?

Our requirement is to have a custom lead conversion, where I have designed a screen flow, but an additional requirement is to be able to add existing accounts as well. If this is not possible I was thinking of providing a choice initially - either use an existing account or create a new one, and use them in the flow later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You can do that
2. Drag a Lookup element into the flow which would refer to Accounts
3. Create an apex class which would call a standard Lead convert https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_dml_convertLead.htm
4. Pass the accountId and the leadId to the apex class
5. Use an Invocable action in screen to call the apex class
6. https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_annotation_InvocableMethod.htm
7. Return the required details from that apex class
8. You can refer those attributes into screen.

Comment: Sorry I was unable to comprehend your answer completely. But just to be clear on my part, the requirement is to have a lead conversion process where the user can either choose to enter account name manually with the flow mapping some lead fields to account, or have an existing account be used through a lookup. This solution would suffice?

Comment: Yes, with the above solution, this is possible. Drag a lookup element in your screen where as an picklist option your accounts will be listed  as you go on typing and once a user select an account the lookup element will return that selected AccountId.Now all you need to do is create an apex class which would convert that lead for you. This apex class will be using the standard leadConvert process in that you just have to pass the LeadId and an optional accountId. Even If AccountId is not passed a new account will be created for your lead

Comment: Ohh got it. I shall try thank  you!

Comment: Can you please upvote it as well! :)

Comment: I tried but I am really sorry! I am a beginner so I do not have the ability to do it yet.. I need 15 reputation. :(